# How to dynamically initialize a class instance at runtime in Typescript (Nodejs/Deno)

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I am working with Deno and Typescript;
say I have a main class called 'A' in this example.
And I wanted some other classes with unique methods to extend this class 'A'

So like:

```
class A {
   name: string,
   ...random props

   constructor(_name: string) {
      this.name = _name;
   }

   ...some generic methods(): {}
}


class B extends A {
   specialMethodOne() {
      some code ...
   }
}

class C extends A {
   specialMethodTwo() {
      some code ...
   }
}

class D extends A {
   specialMethodThree() {
      some code ...
   }
}


function Main() {
   const role = some async/await asking function(): string {
       "What role are you??"
        return role of some string (it would be 'B', 'C' or 'D')
   }

   const person = new **[role (B, C, or D)]**("Timmy");
}
```

So in this situation I want to ask the user at runtime for their 'role' which would relate to classes 'B', 'C' or 'D'. Then use their returned answer to initialize the class. The classes have unique methods per role. So I am not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to instantiate a class after testing the role string. Then you set the return type to `A | B | C`. Lastly, whatever instance is returned must be tested to see what class it is *before* you call any class specific methods.

Here's a working example:

```
// Store role names as string somewhere
const ROLES = ['B', 'C', 'D'] as const

// Role base class
class A {
  name: string
  constructor(_name: string) {
    this.name = _name
  }
}

// Role specific classes
class B extends A {
  b(): string { return 'I am B'}
}
class C extends A {
  c(): string { return 'I am C'}
}
class D extends A {
  d(): string { return 'I am D'}
}

// Get a random role, for example sake.
function getRole(): 'B' | 'C' | 'D' {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ROLES.length)
  return ROLES[index]
}

// Get a random role, then instance the correct role class.
function Main(): A | B | C {
  const role = getRole()
  const myName = 'Timmy'

  let person: A | B | C
  if (role === 'B') person = new B(myName)
  else if (role === 'C') person = new C(myName)
  else if (role === 'D') person = new D(myName)
  else throw new Error(`Unknown role: ${role}`)

  return person
}

// Get a role instance. It could be an instance of B, C or D.
const roleInstance = Main()

// Test for the desired class before you call any class specific methods.
if (roleInstance instanceof B) roleInstance.b()
if (roleInstance instanceof C) roleInstance.c()
if (roleInstance instanceof D) roleInstance.d()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=49&pc=48#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-RlHVn88XS-UK5Ya8kG63qh3zYqB9Gx8QM7nTUv4pvw45e9NyBZ893gN8jxPPJkC3B9QGEWBkASAADABVdBaXQaB6F2UtAgAEg8UsqmQm1bU2e1QFXLgPWxXFfXnCgSAjBlQD2aVOCiFBplASxEAJMNmNZRBoDPORlEuclNEZOtSz2cNhMVTBszIsx23waUyVgUBozlPAyAQHikwIPitMQBtoCicJMBQFBCHQBteiGPBWnaLoelwPJoFmRkvzkhTI0EyAWNE4Ysn8oTI0KRYbT8ix5Miz8AvgULVHC+LksKJ5YrPb80AS4LFKYwrI1CzR0vyzKoQyIA)

---

I've left this verbose on purpose to illustrate what is going on but there's a lot of refactoring that could be done. But it's hard to advise more with such a contrived example.

For example, you create a dictionary of role names to role classes `const roles = { A: A, B: B, C: C }` and then something like `new roles[getRole()]('Timmy')`. Now adding new supported classes is pretty easy.